# How to solve a Problem Faced in Colab.Research.Google?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Can anybody help in resolving the issue while generating a video.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1L4PHcU_1h9R28EwvxHQctKWO26mUd2Xt?usp=sharing

The above URL is for Faceswap and while doing the entire process of Faceswap the result was received for the first time but when the process is run for the second time and then after then it is showing below mentioned error in the end.

How to solve this error in Colab.Research.Google? Why is this error coming?

> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
> raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

As per the video given below, I tried exactly the way it is shown in the video but Second time, the video or image is not generating.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7G8ECJ_0l4